# How can I get the width and height of a div(item class) using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, dom

```
<?php
   $htmlString = '<div class="item"><table width="100%" cellpadding="2" class="nobr" autosize="1"><tbody><tr><td width="5%" style="vertical-align:middle;">img tag</td><td width="95%">Test Image td</td></tr></tbody></table></div>'
?>
```

How can I get the width of item class?

Comment: it can only be done on server side via javascript, php will serve this text as html. php can find size of a file or retrieve datas from a file(and send them to the browser)  but cannot see how renders what it's been sent to the browser.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you just need to extract the value of the width, from that string you can use a regular expression. Instead, if you need to evaluate the width when that div is rendered, you have to do that on the client, with javascript, as the rendered size depends on the size of the client that is browsing your page.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know You can't and you don't have to use PHP to get this type of data because PHP is a server side language at least you can assign a fixed width and then use this variable on your language, but usually you have to use a scripting language to work with object rendered in the DOM tree.

Your PHP code arrives from the server so it has no access to this information since the DOM is part of the browser (Client)

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a server side language , I doubt you can use it to obtain the height of a division.
However, you can use jQuery to do that:

```
var height=$(".item").height();
var width=$(".item").width();
```